# WCF could not establish to a laptop using wireless

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets, tcp

I am trying to establish a point-to-point connection using WCF on Windows 7x64 and Studio 2012 Professional. The WPF stop working when the laptop is using wireless.

My computer is connecting to the network switch by ethernet cable and my laptop is connecting to the same network using wired, the WCF DOES works.

But,

When my computer is connecting to the network switch by ethernet cable and my laptop is connecting to the same network using WIRELESS, the WCF DOES NOT works.

And I did update the port number between wired and wireless.

Any help of answer is greatly appreciated.

The error is as follow:

```
Error()
{
    System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Could not connect to net.tcp://100.100.1.90:9000/test_robot_client. The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:01.0430000. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 100.100.1.90:9000.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 100.100.1.90:9000
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

    Server stack trace: 
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedConnectionInitiator.Connect(Uri uri, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
}
```

I see the above error using the Catch(Exception ex) when trying to send a WCF command.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the WCF service hosted in IIS ?

Comment: It says that _target machine actively refused it_ so I would check the firewall on the server. Try even to disable the firewalls on both server and client to be sure that no one is denying network communication.

Comment: The WCF service is not host in IIS. Its just tcp.

I tried to turn off both server and client's firewall. I even turned off Avast. Problem still exist. Any idea what's next?

Comment: Its weird....if i were to run the server on the laptop and the client on my pc then I can establish the WCP connection while my laptop is on wireless.

Comment: I got a fix for it. I read somewhere and someone mention to open port 808. So I did that and it works!
Thanks everyone for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a fix for it. I read somewhere and someone mention to open port 808. So I did that and it works! Thanks everyone for helping!!